# Working with a shut-down state of a user session on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, shutdown, logoff

Say, if I open a Notepad, type something in it and don't save it, then call the following API from the same user session:

```
ExitWindowsEx(EWX_LOGOFF, SHTDN_REASON_MAJOR_OTHER | SHTDN_REASON_MINOR_OTHER | SHTDN_REASON_FLAG_PLANNED);
```

That user session will enter a "shut-down state", where OS will show an overlay window displaying a message that Notepad prevents system from logging off a user. This overlay will not go away until a user clicks "Cancel" or "Force Quit" buttons.

So two part question:

1. Is there any way to know which processes blocked logging-off/shut-down process?
2. Is there any way to cancel this user-session "shut-down state" programmatically?

PS. This state can be detected by calling GetSystemMetrics([SM_SHUTTINGDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#SM_SHUTTINGDOWN));

**EDIT:** Contrary to the answer below, I *am not* trying to stop system from shutting down, nor that any user-mode process is "hung."

**EDIT2:** Here's a screenshot of the overlay I'm trying to cancel/close:
[image]

Comment: Windows Vista was the start of a much stricter logoff/shutdown. The OS is going to make a difference.

Comment: I technically need it for all, starting from XP.

Comment: this might help http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?147801-How-to-prevent-Windows-Shutdown

Comment: @AnanthaSharma: Thanks, but that is not exactly what I need. You see, the condition I'm talking about it past the moment when log-off process has been initiated.

Comment: Can you specify what type of application you're writing? A windowed application, console, service, etc.?

Comment: @Anthill: It's a local service, but the interaction with a user session comes from a user-mode process.

Comment: So where do you want to detect this? In the user-mode process or in your service?

Comment: So looking at your edit you want to find a way to terminate the process which is blocking the shutdown in order for the system to leave the "shutting down state" and shutdown properly? That's another kettle of fish :)

Answer (score 4):

Question 2: "Is there any way to cancel this shut-down state programmatically?"

The short is answer is not really. And neither should you want to really stop shutdown programatically UNLESS: shutting down will result in serious data loss or significantly affect the user experience on a subsequent system start up. But to mention just one example: imagine a computer is overheating - stopping shutdown programmatically could result in a fried system (and a very irate user).

System shutdown is also not the only thing you need to monitor. There's also hibernate and suspend events (have a look at WM_POWERBROADCAST message).

That said, Windows provides a plethora of mechanisms for detecting system shutdown. For instance:

If your application has a message pump you can choose to return  FALSE when Windows polls running applications to vote on  [WM_QUERYENDSESSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376890%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) , however Windows from Vista onwards will still force a shutdown after a time-out. From Vista onwards you can (and need to) [ShutdownBlockReasonCreate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) after returning false to WM_QUERYENDSESSION.

If your application is running as a service you can use [RegisterServiceCtrHandlerEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685058%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and then [SetServiceStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a 3 minute shutdown extension grace by setting SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN which will get you a SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN notification. Naturally, you won't receive logoff notification because a service is not affected by logoff. Pre-Vista you can register for SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN notification.

Console applications (and gui apps as well but it does not make sense) can use [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to be notified of CTRL_LOGOFF and CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT.

At a much lower level one can try hooking API functions such as NTShutdown or even NtSetSystemPowerState which apparently is ["the last thing called during ANY type of reboot"](http://blogs.technet.com/b/brad_rutkowski/archive/2007/08/25/how-to-catch-shutdowns-that-don-t-go-to-debugger-or-cause-bugchecks.aspx). But I would strongly suggest not to attempt this.

That said there are ways to really strongly insist that the system should not be shutdown.
Consider the following:

1.) Try to register your application to be first in line to receive Shutdown notification. Something like:

```
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686227(v=vs.85).aspx
    if(!SetProcessShutdownParameters(0x4ff, 0)) //  greedy highest documented System reserved FirstShutdown
    {
        // Fallback
        if(!SetProcessShutdownParameters(0x3ff, 0)) // highest notification range for applications
        {
             // shouldn't happen
        }
    }
```

2.) Return FALSE on WM_QUERYENDSESSION
From Vista onwards call ShutdownBlockReasonCreate() after returning false on WM_QUERYENDSESSION.

3.) Tell Windows that you need the system to stay up and available. Have a look at
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373208(v=vs.85).aspx

```
SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS | ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED | ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED);
```

4.) Clean up, call ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy() on Vista onwards, and THEN shutdown the system cleanly.

You could also try the undocumented function (at least it's not on MSDN anymore) CancelShutdown in "user32.dll" which at some point (still may) used to function very much like calling shutdown.exe with the abort flag.

Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks for your long explanation. I agree with all of it. But note that I am not trying to cancel a shutdown. The API I quoted above will simply begin logging off a user and that user session will enter an indefinite "shut-down state" if any process refuses the end-session notification that you listed above. It beats me why they call it that... check the MSDN link for SM_SHUTTINGDOWN I gave above. And that is what I need to cancel?

Comment: @ahmd0 that's the point I'm trying to make: SM_SHUTTINGDOWN (if you're lucky to detect it  by calling it at the right moment) is set after WM_QUERYENDSESSION is sent as far as I can make out - there's no documented way to programmatically cancel the "shut-down state" once it is entered. You could attempt to enumerate processes while in the shutdown state period of grace and attempt to terminate them in order to force the shutdown....

Comment: Well, simply enumerating them won't help because I'm sure there's a ton of Microsoft processes that keep running as well, for instance, explorer.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Following your edit which makes your question clearer:

If you monitor WM_QUERYENDSESSION and respond FALSE to it you can poll from your still running process for a predetermined period of time and then issue an ExitWindowsEx call with flag [EWX_FORCEIFHUNG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for example on WM_ENDSESSION. Or you could actually call this pre-emptively on receiving WM_QUERYENDSESSION - the problem is: what if forcing the shutdown results in serious data loss? You're not doing the user of the system any good at that point.

Update following your comments:

How about this:

To find out blocking application:

1. Register your app with SetProcessShutdownParameters to be first in
   line to get WM_QUERYENDSESSION.
2. Respond FALSE to WM_QUERYENDSESSION and on Vista onwards call
   ShutdownBlockReasonCreate to buy yourself the time.
3. Get the first window in the chain HWND top = GetTopWindow(NULL)
4. Get the  process ThreadId from hwnd GetWindowThreadProcessId() (compare it with your running app's ;) )
5. Use SendMessageTimeOut with a message to the hWnd - if you receive
   no response (timeout) you *may* have found the blocking window. Go to step 6.
   If not skip to 7.
6. Use OpenProcess() with the handle returned from
   GetWindowThreadProcessId to get a process handle and call
   GetModuleBaseName() to get the name of the hung process.
7. If you haven't found the hung window, enumerate the next Window with
   GetNextWindow() and go back to step 4.

You can also try using the enumerate window handle technique above to find out if you can get a handle to the "hung window" overlay. Having this might give you a chance to do a send key to cancel the state. My bet is that you won't be able to access it but I haven't tried :)

Again your mileage may vary :)

Comment: No. I am not trying to terminate any processes, nor that any process is "hung" either. In my example, the Notepad can't quit because it has unsaved data, and I do NOT want to force it to quit. What I'm trying to do is to terminate the Windows "shut-down state" (see the screenshot above) since the "soft" log-off was unsuccessful. This should revert the user session back into the working state. This is what I'm trying to do :)

Comment: The goal for doing this is so that I can run user-mode process, because CreateProcessAsUser won't go through if user session is in that state.

Comment: The short answer is: you can't :) And the long answer is: you can't cancel the hung state without forcing a shutdown as far as I am aware.

Comment: Well, that seems like what I'm finding out. Although what about those "special" cases? I'm sure that overlay is just a window. Is there any way to simulate the "Cancel" button press on it?